# How to return the frequently occurring day in TABLEAU?

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I am working on a dashboard in Tableau where I want to display in a scorecard type of chart the busiest day. I have a data column in timestamp format and I wanted to be able to extract the day of week then show only the most frequently occurring day in a scorecard.

I can get the mode by displaying a table then sorting its Count in descending order. However, what I intend to show is a scorecard with only the MODE on display.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau features you can research that can be helpful for this type of problem are top filters, LOD calculations, Table Calcs and Table Calc filters. In your case, you may also need a custom date field or just a calculation calling DatePart() or DatePartName()

The simplest approach is often a top filter, but the others can be helpful in more complicated situations.

So try putting your weekday field on the filter shelf, select the top tab on the filter dialog and filter to the Top 1 Weekdays based COUNT() of some field.